# Get throu each div and change class on Button-click

Tags: javascript, jquery

Heyo,

I cant figure out how to make a Script work like this: I want to have a Button that changes the Class of `div`'s on `click`. But I don't want to make it change all the `div`'s at the same time. I only want to change the first `div` on the first `click`, the second `div` on the second `click` and so on and so forth.

I've allredy tryed it but failed. Heres the code:

```js
$('button').click(function() {
  // give first $(.div).addClass('active') on first click, second div on second click ...
});
```

```css
.active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="outer">
  
  <div class="inner">
    <div class="div">Somebody</div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="inner">
    <div class="div">once</div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="innner">
    <div class="div">told</div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="inner">
    <div class="div">me</div>
  </div>
  
  <button>Next</button>
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the `.eq` method, you can pass the index of the element you want, and the jQuery collection of only that element will be returned. Start with an index of 0, increment it on every button click, and add the class to the appropriate element:

```js
let i = 0;
$('button').click(function() {
  $('.div').eq(i).addClass('active');
  i++;
});
```

```css
.active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="outer">
  
  <div class="inner">
    <div class="div">Somebody</div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="inner">
    <div class="div">once</div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="innner">
    <div class="div">told</div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="inner">
    <div class="div">me</div>
  </div>
  
  <button>Next</button>
  
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Is there also a simple way to include a Back button?

Comment: Sure, just subtract in that handler instead, and `removeClass` (after decrementing)

Comment: yeah ... i know i allredy did that but i ment a second Button called "Back" which reverses the next button action. I tryed copying the script and wrote at the end 'i--;' instead of 'i++;' but it still keeps jumping foreward the first time you press the Back button. After that thoe it works as i wanted it to do.

Comment: Of course, with additional buttons, you'll also need to select them distinctly somehow - the current `$('button')` will select *any* button. You might select one with `#next` and `#previous`

Answer (score 2):

Here a little one liner that grabs the first element that doesn't has the `active` class.

```js
$('button').click(function() {
  $('.div:not(.active):first').addClass('active');
});
```

```css
.active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="outer">
  
  <div class="inner">
    <div class="div">Somebody</div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="inner">
    <div class="div">once</div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="innner">
    <div class="div">told</div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="inner">
    <div class="div">me</div>
  </div>
  
  <button>Next</button>
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can find the first element and add the `active` class on that. Then rotate the class so on.

```js
$('button').click(function() {
  var activeElem = $('.outer').find('.inner.active');
  if(activeElem.length){
    activeElem.removeClass('active');
    activeElem.next('.inner').addClass('active');
  } else {
    $('.outer').find('.inner').first().addClass('active');
  }
});
```

```css
.active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="outer">

  <div class="inner">
    <div class="div">Somebody</div>
  </div>

  <div class="inner">
    <div class="div">once</div>
  </div>

  <div class="inner">
    <div class="div">told</div>
  </div>

  <div class="inner">
    <div class="div">me</div>
  </div>

  <button>Next</button>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Increment for each click and apply:

```js
var count = 0;

$('button').click(function() {
  $('.inner:eq('+count+')').addClass('active');
  count++;
});
```

```css
.active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="outer">

  <div class="inner">
    <div class="div">Somebody</div>
  </div>

  <div class="inner">
    <div class="div">once</div>
  </div>

  <div class="inner">
    <div class="div">told</div>
  </div>

  <div class="inner">
    <div class="div">me</div>
  </div>

  <button>Next</button>
```